# How can I render multiple elements after an inline condition using short circuit evaluation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using a short circuit evaluation in a functional component (with hooks):

```
const Filters = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      {options.length > 0 && (
        <div className="col-md-3">
          <CustomComponent />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to render multiple elements right after an inline if condition?

```
{options.length > 0 && (
  <div className="col-md-3">
    <CustomComponent />
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-3">
    <SecondComponent />
  </div>
)}
```

Code above doesn't work, react throws an error. `options` array is filled after a promise resolved from `useEffect()`. That's why i've added this check, to display elements only when a promise resolved.

**UPDATED CODE for @wentjun:**

```
return (
  {options.length > 0 && (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <CustomComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
  )
```

This throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the elements in [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax). The reason being, React elements are rendered via a single root node element. Wrapping it in Fragments will allow you to group the elements without adding additional nodes.

```
return (
  <div className="row">
    {options.length > 0 && (
      <>
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <CustomComponent />
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-3">
        <SecondComponent />
      </div>
    </>
  )}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Nice trick! Didn't thought about fragments at all. Also i couldn't put my inline if right after `return (`, that's because of single root node element in a component?

Comment: It should work fine. Is it because you remove the parent div? Do you mind posting your updated code on your question?

Comment: @AlexanderKim ah, yes, you shouldn't have removed that parent div that is wrapping it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the error is due to returning two react elements. Try wrapping then in fragment

```
{options.length > 0 && (
  <>
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <CustomComponent />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <SecondComponent />
    </div>
  </>
)}
```